# Renaming my Laravel 4 root directory makes it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I got Laravel 4 zip file from gitHub. ("**laravel-master**").
run composer and get all the dependencies.
i can access it from: "**127.0.0.1/laravel-master/public**"

but when i rename the "laravel-master" to other names, and then try to access it, i get:

*"HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."*

I can not figure out what's going wrong !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your vhost docroot to /public most likely. You shouldn't be able to access it at /public since that should be the root.

Comment: could you help me more on "vhost docroot" and where should i configure it ?!

Comment: Is this a linux or windows machine?

Comment: Not a MAC guy, but here are the instructions: http://sawmac.com/mamp/virtual/  -- Make sure that when you specify the DocumentRoot that it ends in /public

i.e. /var/www/myapp/public

Comment: Thank you for your time, i think it will help

Answer (score 0):

Because you specifically mentioned MAMP (in the comments to an answer below), try going to Preferences on the MAMP app page, and click "--" in the cache dropdown of the PHP tab.

A simple refresh after that cleared up this same issue for me.

see Apathetic012's comment on a similar issue on Github (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/625)

EDIT: specifying where MAMP was mentioned.